# Cast 'IDOCTYPE_READ_COMPLETE' to 'RfcRepository' [.Net Connector 3]

Tags: sap-dotnet-connector, idoc

I'm working on C# application for one of our customers. We have already defined some IDOC structures. All the specifications are in an Excel sheet.

So the question is: It's possible to get the whole IDOC structure from the 'IDOCTYPE_READ_COMPLETE' function and parse / load it somehow to a 'RfcStructureMetadata' object?

Additional info: Im allowed to send IDOC to the ABAB backend just with the 'IDOC_INBOUND_ASYNCHRONOUS' function > 'IDOC_DATA_REC_40' table > 'SDATA' field. But I can't create any Structure since I do not have any metadata yet.

Hopefully makes sense, Thank you in advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no easy / build in way to achieve this with the SAP NCO 3 connector. Are the todo's if someone wants to communicate with SAP just with the `IDOC_INBOUND_ASYNCHRONOU` RFC function.

1. Get the IDoc structure with `IDOCTYPE_READ_COMPLETE` function.
2. Write functions which can cast from and to the `SDATA` field from the `IDOC_DATA_REC_40` table to your own 'business' objects. To 'cut' the `SDATA` field you will need the `EXTLEN` field (`IDOCTYPE_READ_COMPLETE` function `PT_FIELDS` table). This is something like char offset.
3. Be aware that IDOC can contain multiple segments and/or list of segments. And the same for segments (recrusion). The references are maintained with the `SEGNUM` and `PARNO`, you have to set these in the `IDOC_INBOUND_ASYNCHRONOUS` function `IDOC_DATA_REC_40` table. You can get these values in `IDOCTYPE_READ_COMPLETE` function and `PT_SEGMENTS` table.

Answer (score 1):

This thread might be of interest for you:
[SAP .Net Connector 3.0 - How can I send an idoc from a non-SAP system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45354130/sap-net-connector-3-0-how-can-i-send-an-idoc-from-a-non-sap-system/45378463#45378463) 

What has been discussed there is still valid.

If you have a choice, I'd recommend to switch to Java and use the [SAP Java Connector](https://support.sap.com/jco) plus the IDoc Class Library add-on for working with IDocs. With this you don't need to deal with all the technical IDoc stuff anymore and can directly start with implementing the business logic for processing your IDocs.

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately, I can't switch to the Java connector. Our whole solution based on .Net. I have already seen the [SAP .Net Connector 3.0 - How can I send an idoc from a non-SAP system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45354130/sap-net-connector-3-0-how-can-i-send-an-idoc-from-a-non-sap-system/) thread. I need the same thing like the Maxime Trembay did. Programatically create metadata by querying the SAP...

Comment: In this case IDOCTYPE_READ_COMPLETE can indeed provide all necessary IDoc meta data. But I doubt that class RfcStructureMetadata will be helpful or provides an advantage. You do not send or receive IDocs with using such RFC meta data. The RFC meta data that you need is the one from IDOC_INBOUND_ASYNCHRONOUS and its parameters. For storing the IDoc segment structure meta data you may of course also reuse RfcStructureMetaData but you don't need to. It's up to you how you deal and store this. The IDoc content is finally stored in the SDATA field - which is a CHAR type and not a structure.

Comment: Working without specific metadata defined could work. Follow-up question: how do I  construct this SDATA field without the metadata _(our IDOCs consist of multiple segments)_ . The initial idea was to create an IRfcSturcture and and just `table.CurrentRow.SetValue("SDATA", theStructure);` AFAIK is not possible without the metadata. Found [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34898765/9031787).

Comment: Please read again my previous comment. I did not say that you can make it without IDoc meta data, I only said that storing this IDoc meta data in class RfcStructureMetadata does not make much sense to me. You have to do in .NET what this IDoc Class Library is doing in Java. It also uses own IDoc meta data classes. And you cannot set SDATA from an RFC structure. SDATA is a CHAR type field and AFAIK these types cannot be converted into each other. I think you have to build the SDATA string on your own with considering the respective IDoc segment structure meta data, i.e. offsets and lengths.